# Formulae for remaining principal of a loan with non-constant interest.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I came across the issue where we have amortizing loan with constant annual interest rate and payments throughout the life of the loan. However the actual monthly rate being non-constant (and based on ACT/360 or ACT/365 DCB). For example the annual rate for the loan is 10%, but the MONTHLY rate will vary slightly based on the number of actual days in a particular month. Is there a generic formula to calculate remaining principal amount after k payments?

Thanks